# How do I use property-based urls in OpenFeign in Native/AOT mode without LoadBalancers?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, spring-native, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud OpenFeign (v4.0.2) to create a @FeignClient that uses an url set by a property given in runtime or through Spring Cloud Config.

```java
@FeignClient(name = "my-client")
public interface MyClient {
    @GetMapping("/getCustomers")
    List<String> getCustomers();
}
```

I want to set the url in an application.yaml file:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          my-client:
            url: http://client-service/
    refresh:
      enabled: false
```

I've followed the [documentation about AOT/Native support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#aot-and-native-image-support), but I get the following error while running a native image:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Feign Client for loadBalancing defined. Did you forget to include spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer?

I don't want to use Spring Cloud LoadBalancer, but in the given documentation it says:

> However, if you set the url value via properties, it is possible to override the @FeignClient url value by running the image with -Dspring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.[clientId].url=[url] flag. In order to enable overriding, a url value also has to be set via properties and not @FeignClient attribute during buildtime.

On the other hand, in [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/517), @OlgaMaciaszek says that:

> It is by design. If an empty url has been provided, we try resolving the instance with the LB.

So, is it possible to use OpenFeign in native mode with property-based urls without using LoadBalancers? The documentation is not clear about this:

- If I build the native image with @FeignClient(url = "${spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.my-client.url}") I won't be able to override it during runtime
- If I build the native image with @FeignClient() AOT tries to resolve it with LoadBalancers.

Comment: I was able to get it working by passing the parameters as arguments to the executable, i.e. by passing `-Dspring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.my-client.url=http://client-service/`.